# Charging a battery project

Tags: voltage, batteries

There is this voltage source that generates different types, it is not a sine wave properly (A), then passing it to a full bridge rectifier, the outcome is like B, then you use a smoothing capacitor and the outcome is like C, what do you use to generate a steady voltage? I tried with a 5V voltage regulator, but it is not working, and the inputs are usually higher than 5V. It is to charge a battery (3.7 V), do you strictly require constant DC?

[image]

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: What is producing this output? Depending on its output impedance, a buck-boost controller could give you very exact control of the output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the voltage doesn't exceed the safe voltage for the battery then a precise DC supply isn't too important - depends on the battery technology/chemistry.
In fact having a lead-acid battery being charged in parallel was a common way of smoothing DC before solid-state DC-DC regulators.

**But** 3.7v suggests you are trying to charge a Lithium-Ion battery, this can get dangerous if you overcharge it. You really need a charger-controller IC for Li-Ion, or at the least a protected cell

Comment: And if it does exceed the safe voltage?

Comment: Batteries in general smell really bad when they catch fire.

Comment: It's less common with batteries these days, but it should be said that some lithium batteries used materials that would react explosively with air - that is, pure lithium. Most batteries using lithium compounds are  much less reactive now, but understand that you could be up against a piece of metal that is _on fire_.

Comment: A burning road flare is a useful comparison.  Lithium cobalt oxide makes its own oxygen when burning.

Answer (score 0):

1) A sufficient filter built of capacitors and inductors will smooth the signal. Look into the "pi shaped filter" of two capacitors with an inductor between them. If you are still seeing bad power, then add higher capacitance and inductance (or get a better power source.)

2) If the ouptut of your power source is > 5V, then a 3.3V regulator, or a 1.25V regulator with adjustable output, should be able to be set to the output voltage you want. As long as input voltage - regulator drop is > desired voltage, you're good.

3) If you're charging LiPo based batteries, GET A REAL CHARGER. LiPo batteries that are not strictly controlled when charging have burned down houses. This danger is real. A "B6" style charger can be had on eBay for < $15.

That being said, if you can guarantee that the output voltage will never go above 3.9V, it may be less dangerous to charge the LiPo, because it may never saturate at that voltage, and end up "floating" in the middle. However, it will also not fully charge the battery, and will end up wearing it out in the end.

So, big filter, plus adjustable-voltage regulator, should generate the voltage you want. A boost/buck DC DC converter can be used to accept a large range of input voltages and provide a constant output voltage, as long as the input current is sufficient for the load power. Pololu sells some reasonable-cost ones.

Answer (score -1):

At first - I want to point out that Li-Ion and Li-Po batteries should be charged only with well designed chargers. Battery voltage, current, and temperature changes (caused by power disspated on internal resistance) must be always under control while charging.

For chemical point of view - constant and stable DC is not required by batteries. However you HAVE TO control that voltage and be sure, that maximum voltage on battery is below maximum voltage for your battery type.

[image]

For example - Li-Ion batteries are highly vulnerable to voltages above 4.2V. Irreversible chemical reaction happens and battery looses capacity permanently.

[image]

Voltage "shape" is not that important. You can use your [B] or [C] "shapes" and charge battery with pulses with peak voltage always below maximum cell voltage.